# Starting countdown in update func

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to start a countdown after I add a sprite to make sure other sprites will add/ functions will be called after a certain amount of time. So far I have made sure the variable `countdownCanStart` will change from false to true as I add my sprite.
Inside the `touchesBegan` function:

```
        //adding the sprite by touch
        addSprite()

        if spriteAdded {
            countdownCanStart = true

        }
```

Then in the update func:

```
    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    if countdownCanStart {
        var framecount = 0
        framecount++

        if framecount == 10 {
            AddTheOtherSprites()
        }
    }


}
```

The code runs, it doesn't crash, but next to the row `AddTheOtherSprites()` I see a yellow warning sign: "Will never be executed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is due to `framecount` being a local scoped var (in regards to the update method) ,so every time the update method will be called `framecount` will be initialized with 0 and incremented by 1 so it will never be equal to 10.

Change the scope of `framecount` to be outside the update method

Answer (score 2):

You're creating `framecount` within your `update` method, therefore a new `framecount` is created every time `update` begins and destroyed when `update` ends. Because of this the maximum `framecount` will ever reach is 1 (from `framecount++`) and so `framecount == 10` always returns `false`. To solve this, place `framecount` **outside** your `update` method.

Answer (score 2):

In your `update` function, you are declaring a fresh variable `framecount` and initializing it to 0.  Then incrementing it, then checking if it’s equal to 10.  It never will be - every time you run `update`, a new `framecount` variable will be declared and it will only ever be of value 1 when it’s tested against 10 in the `if` statement.